# Convert Assembly MIPS to C with while

Tags: c, assembly, mips

Can you help me to convert from assembly MIPS to C with while? $s2=result; $s0=&M . Thanks in advance!

```
    addi $t1, $s0, 400 # with this I have &M[0] so &M[100]?
    WHILE: lw $s1, 0($t1) #$s1=M[i];
    add $s2, $s2, $s1# result=result+M[i];
    addi $t1, $t1, -4# i=i-1;
    bne $t1, $s0, WHILE
```

Maybe is this?

```
i=100;
while (i!=0) {
result=result+M[i];
i--; 
}
```

Comment: Technically it's a `do {} while` since the test is at the end and it's using pointers not indexing but your code is equivalent.

Comment: [Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](//stackoverflow.com/a/47790760) explains why `do{}while` loops are the normal idiomatic way to loop in asm, so any normal `for()` or `while` loops that always run at least 1 iteration are compiled that way.